# Using generics to assert an optional parameter that can be "void | any"?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to assert that a type can be `void | any` but TypeScript is expecting a value to be provided.

```js
type ObservableConstructor = {
  new (o: (observer: { next(): void }) => void): {}
  new <T0>(o: (observer: { next(v0: T0): void }) => void): {}
  new <T0, T1>(o: (observer: { next(v0: T0, v1: T1): void }) => void): {}
}

declare const Observable: ObservableConstructor

// When using "any" type it asks for an additional parameter
const o1 = new Observable<string, void | any>((o) => {
  // Compilation error here
  o.next('foobar')
})

const o2 = new Observable<string, void | any>((o) => {
  o.next('foobar', undefined)
})

// When not using "any" type, it works fine
const o3 = new Observable<string, void | Error>((o) => {
  o.next('foobar', new Error())
})

const o4 = new Observable<string, void | Error>((o) => {
  o.next('foobar')
})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgZwgJwG4EM4BsIGED2AdgsMgK4DGw%20yUAvFAN4CwAUFFIRAO5QAU%20AFz98iFKhTDGnCAA9gfAJTDU%20AJYATKAF9F9AHxRVm5U21sOXXgB4AKgAZ9A4QLFpJTGfL6p7wh6bGWroGRuoapozm7DI2DgA0ULYAjE5CIm4SyFJeCr7%209omoyf7JgeE6enSGQZHR0WwaEBRY6MjQFEQksJmYOMLwSGh9eF2klNTIbGwA9DNQAOoAFhCEUGQIaoQA5lAAROiEIHtQoJBQasBQ6AgA1ghQAGY012voGhqXakToWFBgbXQAFsIMAUGxOsQrvhkvRYj0hhhsBBrCRkFttkUKgAfV4gJwCKqGFgxfAAOi43gA5M9RG0qYo2LppqxId18AAmOFWBHiEao0gYrGaKC4w74viE0IkjjkykKGn4OnIKmJMiEJqPLYQCJMxmsWbzZarTj4K4bDH7cUnM4QRKXKDcGj3J7aiFjKD4ADM3J4vOGyIF6J2wq0uIAoshkDQCfgiUwLJ6KXIFbS4PTEjzI9HkEp9cyDayPfgACy%203iDPmBtFCsIiiNRmOSuPSxNylN8RXKhl6oA)

Comment: Would `void | {} | undefined | null` work well enough for your use cases?  `any` and `unknown` absorb unions so `void | any` is just `any` and `void | unknown` is just `unknown`.